# We have a list named List1 = [[1,2,4],[5,6,7],[8,9,10]]. Getting result using indexing but when i tryin using for loop getting error

Tags: for-loop, indexing

```
List1 = [[1,2,4],[5,6,7],[8,9,10]]
List1 [0][1] = 2


for i in list1:
    print((i)[0][1])
```

output :

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Shall we get the same result or not, if not why?

Comment: The error message is very clear and self-explanatory.

Comment: _"Shall we get the same result or not, if not why?"_ No, because `List` is a list of lists of numbers and `i` is a list of numbers. That's a big difference. `List[0]` is list and `i[0]` is a number.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the language here is python.
In this case, the `i` represents the sub-list(s) that you are looping through.

So if you would like to print each sublist, you can do:

```
list1 = [[1,2,4],[5,6,7],[8,9,10]]

for i in list1:
    print(i)

# output:
# [1, 2, 4]
# [5, 6, 7]
# [8, 9, 10]
```

If you'd like to print only the first element of each sub-list, you can use an index:

```
list1 = [[1,2,4],[5,6,7],[8,9,10]]

for i in list1:
    print(i[0])

# output:

# 1
# 5
# 8
```

Comment: Thanks m_vemuri.                                                                                                             
 Yes, language is python. When i running this query getting result                                              for  i in list1:
    print(i[0]) but when i trying                                                                                               
   for  i in list1:
    print(i[0][1]) getting error.. Now Thomas has cleared this thing here "i" is number not list.